# Como puedo consumir un webservice desde una aplicación windows con vb.net

Tags: vb.net

Hago esto:

- Abro una nueva aplicación de Windows
- Agrego una referencia de servicio
- Cambio el espacio de nombres a ws1 y hago clic en aceptar

Aquí recibo la primera sorpresa. En lugar de ver la lista de métodos manejados por el servicio web, veo un icono

En el archivo **`App.config`** puedo ver esto:

```
<cliente>
        <dirección de punto final = "http: //cwp-vm-matrixw/Tiendas/service.asmx"
            binding = "basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration = "ServiceSoap"
            contract = "ws1.ServiceSoap" name = "ServiceSoap" />
</cliente>
```

Lo que he probado:

Dentro del código trato de escribir esto:

```
Dim wsMio As New ws1.ServiceSoap
```

Pero recibo el error:

> New no se puede usar en una interfaz

Cuando escribo `Dim wsMio As ws1.ServiceSoap` si puedo seguir adelante.

```
Private Sub Bt (remitente como System.Object, e como System.EventArgs) maneja Button1.Click
            Dim wsMio como ws1.ServiceSoap
            TextBox1.Text = wsMio.Dobla (5)
End Sub
```

En este caso, cuando escribo wsMio., puedo ver la lista de métodos, elijo Dobla (método que duplica un valor dado) y acepta el código, pero cuando hago clic en el botón, en lugar de recibir el valor 10, recibo un error: Referencia de objeto no establecido en una instancia de un objeto. Utilice la palabra Nuevo para crear una instancia del objeto.

¿Alguna idea para continuar?

¿Está bien no recibir la lista de métodos cuando agrego la referencia de servicio, o ya de inicio he hecho algo mal?

¿Cómo puedo declarar una nueva instancia del objeto ws1 usando New, como debe ser?